# inline-block elements not showing in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, css

So, this is an odd one...

I've got basic pagination code:

```
<div class="pagination">
    <a href="#" class="prev">&lt;</a> <a href="#">1</a> <a class="current">2</a> <a href="#">3</a> <a href="#" class="next">&gt;</a>
</div>
```

And I want it all centred, so I'm using inline-block on the anchor tags. Simple enough, stripped down CSS code:

```
.pagination{text-align:center; margin-bottom:20px;}
.pagination > a{display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; margin:0 2px 0 1px;}
.ie7 .pagination > a{zoom:1;}
.pagination .next,
.pagination .prev{width:26px; height:38px; text-indent:-9999px; overflow:hidden;
background:url(../images/page-arrows.png) no-repeat;}
.pagination a{width:37px; height:31px; line-height:32px; font-size:15px; font-weight:bold; color:#7e7e7e;
background:url(../images/page-numbers.png) left top no-repeat;}
```

Problem is that, NOTHING is displaying in IE7 (at least IE7-mode of IE9). I'm well aware of the display-inline bugs that IE7 has, but those only apply to elements that aren't inline by default. I've added in a zoom:1 anyway though for good measure.

If I put a background colour on the .pagination wrapper, that wrapper does indeed show up with the background colour, but the elements inside just aren't showing!

I've tried the usual IE 'fixes' ...position:relative, zoom:1, height:1% on any and every element, but not luck.

What am I missing?!

Comment: You could experiment with floating the pagination hyperlinks, rather than using inline-block. That might be a little easier to deal with in IE7.

Comment: Of course floats are safer, but to center it all would require an extra div and floating stuff left:50%, left:-50%, and overflow hidden and all that jazz. Prefer to keep it simpler if possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimenting in JSFiddle I've managed to discover that the problem relates to this particular rule

```
.pagination .prev {text-indent:-9999px; }
```

Disabling this fixes the issue but is not ideal as you would then have the text charecter appear on top of your background images.

Interestingly enough your `.next` does not cause the same issue. with that in mind added an `&nbsp;` to either side of your paging control (so your center alignment dosnt get skewed) and it seems to of fixed the problem.

```
<div class="pagination"> 
    &nbsp; 
    <a href="#" class="prev">&lt;</a> <a href="#">1</a> <a class="current">2</a> <a href="#">3</a> <a href="#" class="next">&gt;</a> 
    &nbsp;
</div>
```

[JSFiddle available here](http://jsfiddle.net/t9QA2/) (background images replaced with solid colors for obvious reasons)

Comment: Wow, nice one for figuring that out - who would have thought! Thanks :)